# While loops doesn't work inside a with block

Tags: python

I'm trying to print out the content of a 'txt' file.
My code:

```
filename = 'I_learned'
n = 0
with open(filename) as file:
  while n == 3:
    print(file.read())
    n += 1
```

When I run the code:

```
atizva@atizva0:~/Documents/Python coding/Programs$ python I_learned.py
atizva@atizva0:~/Documents/Python coding/Programs$
```

Nothing runs.
I don't get where my mistake is at? Isn't it supposed to show the content of the file 3 times? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Try to change your while condition to n < 3.

Comment: Try to change your while condition to n < 3.

Comment: @JeromeEscalante It works but prints the content just once: 
`atizva@atizva0:~/Documents/Python coding/Programs$ python I_learned.py`
`first`
`second`
`third`

`atizva@atizva0:~/Documents/Python coding/Programs$ `

Comment: You can't read a file twice once it's already open. What you can do is to save the contents of the file before you execute the while loop... Like this .. `contents = file.read()` then on your while loop, you can just do `print(contents)`.

Comment: But if you really need to read the file more than once, you can use `file.seek(0)`. It will put the pointer back to the first byte of the file as suggested in this [thread](https://ubuntuforums.org/archive/index.php/t-1527860.html) You can add that at the end of your while loop below the `n += 1` line.

Answer (score 2):

you've already set `n = 0` therefore
 `while n == 3:` results as `False`

you need to change the comparison in while statement

```
filename = 'I_learned'
n = 0
with open(filename) as file:
  while (n < 3):
    print(file.read())
    n += 1
```